# Saving Formula Patterns

Tags: javascript, php, coding-style, save, formula

Short: I need a way to save Formulas, so that I can execute them when I need it

Details: I am writing something for a eccommerce-system, so that the price of a product can be calculated by volume of the product. I want the backend-user (admin, seller of the product) to be able to set **custom formulas** for different ways of **calculating the voluma**. [e.g. `(A x B - C x D) * E;` `A x B x (C - D);`]. They differ in operations used `(*,-,/,+)` and in the amount of variables used in the formula.

I need a way to save this formulas (string is obviously a bad idea) in PHP, so that I can use them when I need them (set A,B,C,D,E to values and get the result) and also pass them by to Javascript and use them there too.

I appreciate any input on how this could be done.

Comment: Why are strings a bad idea? Just validate the strings first (both client and sever) before saving it.

Comment: @elclanrs Because if I have a string, e.g. "A x B x (C - D)" and I have five Variables $a=1, $b=2, $c=3, $d=4 it will be a tough and expensive task to get the computer to calculate 1 x 2 x ( 3 - 4). I need a way of saving the formula, so that I can **easily** calculate with the formula

Comment: If you're going to calculate the formula in the backend you  can simply send a JSON object with the variables and the formula, eg `{"formula":"A+B","A":1,"B":2}`, then do what's necessary in the backend.

Comment: js calculates on front-end. the variables A and B will be set by the end-user of the page. I hoped that there is an easier way, than saving formula patterns as string first and then write a seperate php and javascript function (I have to be able to calculate the formula on both sides) which can translate strings like "A+B+(C-D)" to a usable formula. The function would have to be `function( (string) formula, (array) values)`, translate the formula, set the values from the array to the formula and calculate it. and that in PHP **and** javascript. isn't there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Yup, you have to do the logic twice if you want to be able to calculate on both client and server. Using NodeJS on the backend would be a different story as you could share the same JS code on both sides.

Comment: so actually saving the formula as a string **is** the best way? would some kind of object storing different operators and a order to execute them on different input be better? that's the idea I had, I just don't have an idea how to implement it..

Answer (score 0):

Wow, nice problem! Here are some ideas.

a) Meta programming (is it the right word?)

In JS you can define a formula with a simple statement:

```
var f = new Function('a', 'alert(a)');
```

You can write a startup script which reads all the formula and load then dinamically (querying a webservice for example). This function could be called as expected:

```
f('Here I am');
```

There are many years since i learnt PHP but I think you could try [dynamic includes](http://inobscuro.com/tutorials/read/16/). When user defines a formula you could generate a file on a special folder containing the PHP code representing it. If PHP allows function reference, the formulas could be accessed like:

```
$formulaBag['MyFormula']('Here I am')
```

Since you're allowing the user to insert code in your system, you should avoid "direct programming". Offer your user a small language for formula definition. When it is done, you trigger a process parse the formula-script and generate the corresponding JS and PHP code.

b) Dynamic parsing

It seems you have some performance concerns... if you define a simple language, parsing it in PHP would be not that difficult. Do you expect to run many formulas on a long-time-running process? If not, maybe this is a better option since you will not need to generate dynamic includes (security risk?). Calculating the formula would be something like this:

```
$res = ExecuteFormula($formula_name, $array_of_parameters)
```

[Added]
Parsing is not that difficult. You will need a Finity State Machine and a Stack to "reserve" temporary values when leading parentheses.

Well, I hope it helps.